# Refreshing is not happening in ListView

Tags: android

I am reading some datas from database and displaying it in a listview.After deleting one item from database,i want the list to be updated automatically.I have called notifyDataChanged() method also.But its not refreshing.Help me in this.Thanks

Comment: Add some code, how are you doing that.

Comment: I believe you have data in the database and also some List of objects representing that data in your list adapter (At least that would be normal). So my guess is that you delete data only from a database and not from that List. Then call notityDataSetChanged() and it should work just fine :)

Comment: use yourListView.invalidateViews();

Comment: After deleted row from database then delete (remove) that item from list after make call of notifyDatasetChanged() its work.

Comment: Can u pls tell how to remove an item from the list.Thanks

Comment: Yes,I have done by using remove(info.position) of array and called invalidateViews() method.Thanks for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated and refreshed the list though notifyDataSetChanged() and ListView.invalidateViews().Thanks for all.